# Complex table layout with CSS

Tags: html, css-tables

I created table with `ul` lists and styled as table with CSS `display:table`

The problem is that my table rows should be draggable and grouped in some parts which affects on list behavior like table. Here is my Code http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/38pvx9bn/1/

So In my code `dd-list` is table, `dd-item`is table-row and `dd-handle` is `table-cell`. It works fine when I have only one table, but I need to have nested tables to make some part of row draggable (e.g from `1.draggable` entire row, `2.draggable` only right part of row) . So I set `dd-list` in `dd-list` in each row. This affects on behavior like table, and `table-cell` become independent from each other.

So, what can you advise to get table in table but keep table-cell's dependence from each other?

```css
   .dd-list {
        display: table ;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .dd-item {
        list-style: decimal;
        display: table-row ;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .dd-item, .dd-empty, .dd-placeholder {
        position: relative ;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 20px ;
    }
    .dd-handle {
        display: table-cell ;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 5px 0 ;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none ;
        font-weight: bold ;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .dd-container, .btn-gray {
        border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
```

```html
    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" class="dd-list dd-container ng-scope">
        <li class="dd-item">
            <div class="dd-handle dd-head">-</div>
            <div class="dd-handle dd-head">1.draggable dfdfd</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">2.draggable</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">bbb</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">ccc</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">ddd</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">gg</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-head">ggg</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope angular-ui-tree-nodes" ng-repeat="employee in employees" ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="employees" data-type="employee">
            <div class="dd-handle ng-binding">1</div>
            <div class="dd-handle">
                <edit-in-place id="1" value="employee.name" class="ng-isolate-scope edit-in-place"><span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value" class="ng-binding">test</span>
    
                </edit-in-place>
            </div>
            <ol class="dd-list ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope angular-ui-tree-nodes" ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="employee.contracts" data-type="contract">
           
                <li class="dd-item ng-scope angular-ui-tree-node" ng-repeat="contract in employee.contracts" ui-tree-node="" collapsed="false">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <edit-in-place value="contract.client_name" class="ng-isolate-scope edit-in-place"><span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value" class="ng-binding">fghfghfghfgh</span>
    
                        </edit-in-place>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp; sdfsdgdfg</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                </li>
 
                <li class="dd-item ng-scope angular-ui-tree-node" ng-repeat="contract in employee.contracts" ui-tree-node="" collapsed="false">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <edit-in-place value="contract.client_name" class="ng-isolate-scope edit-in-place"><span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value" class="ng-binding">test</span>
    
                        </edit-in-place>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp; sdfsdgdfg</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dd-handle">&nbsp;</div>
                </li>
     
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Hm... why you don't use tables for displaying tabular data?

Comment: This affects on draggability, this part of functionality is made by angular js and from another developer, which asks me to create it with lists, Btw will that solve the problem?

Comment: user Jquery UI sortable method http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article class="main" >My awesome content here </article>
    <footer class="footer">Some informations here  </footer>
    <header class="header">My site title goes here </header>
    <aside class="sidebar">Here is my side content </aside>
    <aside class="annexe" >Some more side content  </aside>
</div>
```

Now the CSS. Pay attention to the number of lines:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-columns: 200px 15px 1fr 15px 100px;
    grid-rows: (auto 15px)[2] auto;
}

.header, .footer { grid-column-span: 5; }

.sidebar,
.main,
.annexe { grid-row: 3; }
.header { grid-row: 1; }
.footer { grid-row: 5; }

.sidebar { grid-column: 1; }
.main    { grid-column: 3; }
.annexe  { grid-column: 5; }
```

Done. 10 lines. No float. No inline-block. No height. No width. No margin. And if you want to make everything nice on small devices.

Note: I won’t explain the syntax. If you want to understand how works the Grid Layout, please have a look at: [CSS-Tricks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/)